# Auto Mapper Mapping Exception

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

I'm making a blog site project, it gives this error while creating article

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(ArticleCreateDTO dto)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) // validasyon tamamsa
        {
            var article = _mapper.Map<Article>(dto);

            if (article.ImagePath != null) // fotoğraf alınabiliyoorsa
            {
                using var image = Image.Load(dto.ImagePath.OpenReadStream());
                image.Mutate(a => a.Resize(100, 100)); // mutate : değiştirmek demek aslın / foto yeniden şekilleniyor
                Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                image.Save($"wwwroot/images/{guid}.jpg"); // root altına foto kaydı için dosya açtık ve yol verdik.
                article.Image = ($"/images/{guid}.jpg"); // veritabanına dosya yolunu kaydediyor

                _articleRepository.Create(article);
                return RedirectToAction("List");
            }
        }
        //ToDo = Validasyonu geçemezse categories patlamasın diye listeyi doldurup return view alalım
        return View(dto);
    }
```

Exception:

AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types: ArticleCreateDTO -> Article BlogProject_FurkanDurgun.WEB.Areas.Member.Models.DTOs.ArticleCreateDTO -> BlogProject_FurkanDurgun.Models.Entities.Concrete.Article

I would be very grateful if you could help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't post code or error messages as images.

Comment: It says that you should create a map between the ArticleCreateDto and Article in your MappingProfile.